# Linq to select property from XML

Tags: c#, xmldocument, linq-to-xml

This is my first day working with XML in the context of XPath, XQuery, and Linq, and I can't get any of them to work for me.

My goal is to extract values for AgentGUID and PublicKey in a XML blob.  The Linq query I'm using is below.

```
        IEnumerable<string> publicKey =
            from item in xDoc.Descendants("PublicKey")
            select (string)item.????;
```

Here is the XML I'm trying to select from:

```
<AgentRegister xmlns="sampleURI">
server
<Servername>server</Servername>
<AgentGUID>1da3a4cf-73f2-4ee2-b8c1-cef428ad4b21</AgentGUID>
<PublicKey>&lt;RSAKeyValue&gt;&lt;Modulus&gt;5fuiFE74EKYUxFbSsAgeYQwyGzulQ+L1auBD1J/1gupF2s2NugpgZ6vqsi4o//vKdrKz7uhwDWeRUB5TR7hljNfOsJKbTV0sg4HywF93cyYDnfKz+2wCSxiZxAIWV8SMiui2QuD0LjbgPNGR/bBsY4GIl3eWbngjJjNEzVZq5RE=&lt;/Modulus&gt;&lt;Exponent&gt;AQAB&lt;/Exponent&gt;&lt;/RSAKeyValue&gt;</PublicKey>
<ApprovedByGUID>&lt;RSAKeyValue&gt;&lt;Modulus&gt;5fuiFE74EKYUxFbSsAgeYQwyGzulQ+L1auBD1J/1gupF2s2NugpgZ6vqsi4o//vKdrKz7uhwDWeRUB5TR7hljNfOsJKbTV0sg4HywF93cyYDnfKz+2wCSxiZxAIWV8SMiui2QuD0LjbgPNGR/bBsY4GIl3eWbngjJjNEzVZq5RE=&lt;/Modulus&gt;&lt;Exponent&gt;AQAB&lt;/Exponent&gt;&lt;/RSAKeyValue&gt;</ApprovedByGUID>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<DigestValue>2HuOAQAAxOTWz2JSq9+bJnWM8m8=</DigestValue></Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>yGKq/p/JQCWSJtVKeRp4E5kHeFWVaoMFd/TbrYIm6k3nYBgr57gcEZjzvrLNsmKKaoaWspSqMzTDnrhER5AkfMi+4nhW0C6+vghNYU/jrEqT35Ov/B3aH1M41q07p3OXZc8dA1lzJ6Zh0zpx6Vd7faTfvuPqgIKmNOe07xGyP2Q=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>5fuiFE74EKYUxFbSsAgeYQwyGzulQ+L1auBD1J/1gupF2s2NugpgZ6vqsi4o//vKdrKz7uhwDWeRUB5TR7hljNfOsJKbTV0sg4HywF93cyYDnfKz+2wCSxiZxAIWV8SMiui2QuD0LjbgPNGR/bBsY4GIl3eWbngjJjNEzVZq5RE=</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue></KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</AgentRegister>
```

How do I extract the mentioned values from this document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using `XDocument` but without LINQ, if you don't expect the general structure of the document to change.

```
var publicKey = (string)xDoc.Root.Element("PublicKey");
var agentGuid = (Guid)xDoc.Root.Element("AgentGUID");
```

If you know there's only one instance of a given tag, it's less trouble to just go get that instance than to call a method that selects all tags with a given name, and then extract a single value from the resulting `IEnumerable<>`.

However, your original code was almost right.

```
    IEnumerable<string> publicKeys =
        from item in xDoc.Descendants("PublicKey")
        select (string)item;
```

But then you'd have to follow that up with:

```
    string publicKey = publicKeys.First();
```

The `XElement` type defines custom conversion operators for many different primitive types. It has a `Value` property that returns a string, so you could use that and not have any cast at all if a string is what you want - but often it's more convenient to just cast an `XElement` containing a value directly to the data type you want.

**Update**

If you need an `XmlDocument` you can convert an `XDocument` like this...

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xDoc.CreateReader());
```

However, it's probably more efficient to just use an `XmlDocument` to begin with, even if it's less convenient. One way to get the same values from an `XmlDocument` is like this:

```
var publicKey = doc.GetElementsByTagName("PublicKey")[0].InnerText;
var agentGuid = new Guid(doc.GetElementsByTagName("AgentGUID")[0].InnerText);
```

Comment: That's great.. but I just realised that `SignedXml()` requires a XMLDocument or an XMLElement.  Does it make sense to load untrusted XML into more than one object?  More of a security risk?  Should I try to only work within the confines of an XMLDocument?

Comment: BTW - `InnerText` seems to be what I needed instead of `Value`; thanks for your help!

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for not testing my code. Updated the example.